# Android - How to realize REST GET function for REST API in skydrive

Tags: android, rest, httpclient, onedrive

Does anyone know how to use Skydrive REST API in Android?

(documented here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/live/hh243648.aspx)

All Data that are needed for access are already stored!

```
  private String AccessToken;
  private String AuthenticationToken;
  private String RefreshToken;
  private String ExpiresIn;
  private String Scope;
```

Is it right to use

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Does anyone have a full example?

Any ideas or suggestion would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
InputStream result = null;

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/albums?access_token=" + AccessToken); // For example
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

if (response != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    BufferedHttpEntity bufferedHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());
    result = bufferedHttpEntity.getContent();
} else {
    // insert error handling
}
```

Depending on what request you are making you may need to use `HttpPut`, `HttpPost`, `HttpDelete`, etc. instead of `HttpGet`.

> - GET - Returns the representation of a resource.
> - POST - Adds a new resource to a collection.
> - PUT - Updated to the location that was specified as the target URL, or add a resource there, add a resource if one does not exist.
> - DELETE - Deletes a resource.

If the request requires a body, you can add it with `setEntity()` which takes an [HttpEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html/) object.